# Is it possible to view the messages outputted by Microsoft ReportViewer in my own front-end?

Tags: visual-studio, console, debugging, reportviewer

I would like to view the messages displayed by ReportViewer in the output window of Visual Studio when a report is viewed, in my own application.

I assume it would involve intercepting the debug or console output messages. Is this possible?

I am using Microsoft ReportViewer 2008 in local mode.